# Ansible 2.10 playbook task not running with a local connection despite being set in task

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am making a playbook to install some software on both Linux and Windows machines (please note I am just testing with one host group containing one Windows Server, all functionality related to doing commands on different OSs is fine). The playbook is mostly split into two parts, a block that runs for the Windows machines and a block that runs for the Linux machines.

However before this the playbook should locally (on the Controller) run two `shell` commands to download the relevant files from Azure. This should be done without attempting to open a SSH session to the Controller Host, and instead just using a local `shell` (ASFAIK this is done via the `connection: local` var rather than using `delegate_to: localhost`)

When doing so using this block (indents are behaving strange when copying over to here), it still attempts to run the module on the targets causing an error:

```yaml
---
- name: Install agent on selected servers
  hosts: windowsbox
  gather_facts: yes

  vars_files:

    - "group_vars/passwords.yml"
    - "group_vars/windowsbox.yml"

  tasks:

  - name: debug print
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts }}"

  - name: Download agent locally
    shell: |
      redactedcommand
      redactedcommand
    connection: local
    run_once: true
```

The error returned is:

```json
TASK [Download agent locally] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: No python interpreters found for host UKS-99850-WIN (tried ['/usr/bin/python', 'python3.7', 'python3.6', 'python3.5', 'python2.7', 'python2.6', '/usr/libexec/platform-python',
'/usr/bin/python3', 'python'])
fatal: [windowsbox]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"}, "changed": false, "module_stderr": "Exception calling \"Create\" with \"1\" argument(s): \"At line:4 char:21\r\n+ def _ansiballz_main():\r\n+                     ~\r\nAn expression was expected after '('.\r\nAt line:13 char:27\r\n+     except (AttributeError, OSError):\r\n+                           ~\r\nMissing argument in parameter list.\r\nAt line:15 char:29\r\n+     excludes = set(('', '.', scriptdir))\r\n+                             ~\r\nMissing expression after ','.\r\nAt line:15 char:30\r\n+     excludes = set(('', '.', scriptdir))\r\n+                              ~~~~~~~~~\r\nUnexpected token 'scriptdir' in expression or statement.\r\nAt line:15 char:29\r\n+     excludes = set(('', '.', scriptdir))\r\n+                             ~\r\nMissing closing ')' in expression.\r\nAt line:15 char:39\r\n+     excludes = set(('', '.', scriptdir))\r\n+                                       ~\r\nUnexpected token ')' in expression or statement.\r\nAt line:15 char:40\r\n+     excludes = set(('', '.', scriptdir))\r\n+                                        ~\r\nUnexpected token ')' in expression or statement.\r\nAt line:22 char:7\r\n+     if sys.version_info < (3,):\r\n+       ~\r\nMissing '(' after 'if' in if statement.\r\nAt line:22 char:30\r\n+     if sys.version_info < (3,):\r\n+                              ~\r\nMissing expression after ','.\r\nAt line:22 char:25\r\n+     if sys.version_info < (3,):\r\n+                         ~\r\nThe '<' operator is reserved for future use.\r\nNot all parse errors were reported.  Correct the reported errors and try again.\"\r\nAt line:10 char:1\r\n+ $exec_wrapper = [ScriptBlock]::Create($split_parts[0])\r\n+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParseException\r\n \r\nThe expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command \r\nname, a script block, or a CommandInfo object.\r\nAt line:11 char:2\r\n+ &$exec_wrapper\r\n+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadExpression\r\n ", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}
```

As you can see it fails as it tries to run the `shell` module on the Windows Host instead of just on the Controller.

I've tried using `connection: local`, and `delegate_to: localhost` in the vars for the task to no avail. I can make the Linux Targets run the `shell` command remotely to download the file, but it would still not fix it breaking when running against Windows Targets.

I have some alternatives I could do like storing the file in the git repo that everything else is in but it would be preferable both for security and more so I'd prefer to keep it in the remote Azure container, and use only one playbook to install for both groups of devices.

Comment: Can you confirm the path where python is located in the target instance? It is stated that it is a Windows machine, but the path seems to be for linux. You'll need to ensure that the [pre-requisites](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/os_guide/index.html) for Ansible execution in Windows is completed

Answer (score 0):

> *As you can see it fails as it tries to run the `shell` module on the Windows Host instead of just on the Controller*

Right, that's the behavior which is defined within the playbook and since you have used `hosts: windowsbox`. Furthermore you would need to `delegate_to: controlnode` instead of `localhost`. The group of `windowsbox`es doesn't know that there is a Remote Control Node outside and running Linux.

You may have a look into the following minimal example.

```yaml
---
- name: Download relevant files from Azure
  hosts: controlnode.example.com
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Download agent locally
    shell: |
      redactedcommand
      redactedcommand

- name: Install agent on selected servers
  hosts: windowsbox
  gather_facts: yes

  vars_files:

    - "group_vars/passwords.yml"
    - "group_vars/windowsbox.yml"

  tasks:

  - name: Show Windows facts
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts }}"
```

**Further Documentation**

- [Playbook execution](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_intro.html#playbook-execution)
- [Set the order of task execution in Ansible](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ansible-pretasks-posttasks)